# How do I create ordered xml elements in scala?

Tags: xml, scala, scala-xml

This seems wrong to me - why is the order of the elements changed from the order they are built?

```
scala> var list = collection.immutable.TreeSet(1, 3, 2, 5, 0)
list: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Int] = TreeSet(0, 1, 2, 3, 5)

scala> var xml = <list>{ list.map(number => { <number>{number}</number> }) }</list>
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <list><number>3</number><number>1</number><number>2</number><number>5</number><number>0</number></list>

scala> var xml = <list>{ list.map(number => { println(number); <number>{number}</number> }) }</list>
0
1
2
3
5
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <list><number>3</number><number>1</number><number>2</number><number>5</number><number>0</number></list>
```

Answer (score 2):

When you map over the TreeSet, it creates a new set. The new Set does not use the natural ordering for integers, of course, since its elements are not integers. In fact, since there is no natural Ordering for `Elem`, the new set is unordered. You can achieve the ordering you're looking for with:

```
var xml = <list>{ list.toSeq map (n => <number>{n}</number>) }</list>
```

Comment: Actually, I doubt it created a new `TreeSet`, as there's no `Ordering` for the result. More likely, it descended to a `Set`, which defaults to `HashSet`.